# zeromq with pgm on iOS/ OpenPGM on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, zeromq, pgm-protocol

Does anyone know how to setup ZeroMQ to work with OpenPGM for iOS? Or has someone used the openpgm library in an Xcode project as it seems that this library is the source of the problems. ZeroMQ without pgm support works fine on iOS but once I try to use it with pgm Xcode starts generating errors - once I get some of them fixed, new come up. Has someone done this successfully or does someone know that it cannot be done for sure. I am looking for instructions on how to build zmq to work for iOS in my Xcode projects with pgm support.